# Gmail rejects emails. Openspf.net fails the tests. 

Tags: email, gmail, spam, email-spam, spf

I've got a problem with Gmail.

It started after one of our trojan infected PCs sent spam for one day from our IP address.

We've fixed the problem, but we got into 3 black lists. We've fixed that, too. But still every time we send an email to Gmail the message is rejected:

So I've checked Google Bulk Sender's guide once again and found an error in our SPF record and fixed it. Google says everything should become fine after some time, but this doesn't happen. 3 weeks already passed but we still can't send emails to Gmail.

Our mail setup is a bit complex, but not too much. We have a domain name `delo-company.com`, it has it's own mail `@delo-company.com` (this one is fine, but the problems are with sub-domain name `corp.delo-company.com`).

`Delo-company.com` domain has several DNS records fro its subdomain:

```
corp                     A     82.209.198.147
corp                     MX    20 corp.delo-company.com
corp.delo-company.com    TXT   "v=spf1 ip4:82.209.198.147 ~all"
```

(I set ~all for testing purposes only, it was -all before that)

These records are for our corporate Exchange 2003 server at `82.209.198.147`. Its LAN name is `s2.corp.delo-company.com` so its HELO/EHLO greetings are also `s2.corp.delo-company.com`.

To pass EHLO check we've also created some records in `delo-company.com`'s DNS:

```
s2.corp                  A     82.209.198.147
s2.corp.delo-company.com TXT   "v=spf1 ip4:82.209.198.147 ~all"
```

As I understand SPF verifications should be passed in this way:
Out server `s2` connects to MX of the recepient (`Rcp.MX`): EHLO s2.corp.delo-company.com
`Rcp.MX` says Ok, and makes SPF check of HELO/EHLO. It does NSlookup for `s2.corp.delo-company.com` and gets the above DNS-records. TXT records says that `s2.corp.delo-company.com` should be only from IP `82.209.198.147`. So it should be passed.

Then our `s2 server says RCPT FROM: <supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com>`
Rcp.MX` server checks it, too. The values are the same so they should also be positive.

Maybe there is also a rDNS check, but I'm not sure what is checked HELO or RCPT FROM.

Our PTR record for `82.209.198.147` is:

```
147.198.209.82.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN PTR s2.corp.delo-company.com.
```

To me everything looks fine, but anyway all emails are rejected by Gmail.

---

So, I've checked MXtoolbox.com - it says everything is fine, I passed http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html Python check, I did `25port.com` email test. It's fine, too:

```
Return-Path: <supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com>
Received: from s2.corp.delo-company.com (82.209.198.147) by verifier.port25.com id ha45na11u9cs for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Fri, 2 Mar 2012 13:03:21 -0500 (envelope-from <supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=neutral (message not signed)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com
Content-class: urn:content-classes:message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----_=_NextPart_001_01CCF89E.BE02A069"
Subject: test
Date: Fri, 2 Mar 2012 21:03:15 +0300
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft Exchange V6.5
Message-ID: <4C9EB1DB67831A428B2E14052F4A418707E1FF@s2.corp.delo-company.com>
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
Thread-Topic: test
Thread-Index: Acz4jS34oznvbyFQR4S5rXsNQFvTdg==
From: =?koi8-r?B?89XQ0tXOwMsg8MHXxcw=?= <supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com>
To: <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>
```

I also checked with `spf-test@openspf.net`, but it FAILs all the time, no matter which SPF records I make:

```
<s2.corp.delo-company.com #5.7.1 smtp;550 5.7.1 <spf-test@openspf.net>: Recipient address rejected: SPF Tests: Mail-From Result="softfail": Mail From="supruniuk-p@corp.delo-company.com" HELO name="s2.corp.delo-company.com" HELO Result="softfail" Remote IP="82.209.198.147">
```

I've filled [Gmail form](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/request.py?hl=en&nomods=1&contact_type=bulk_senddelo-company.com) twice, but nothing happens.

We do not send spam, only emails for our clients. 2 or 3 times we did mass emails (like New Year Greetings and sales promos) from corp.delo-company.com addresses, but they where all complying to Gmail Bulk Sender's Guide (I mean SPF, Open Relays, Precedence: Bulk and Unsubscribe tags). So, this should be not a problem.

Please, help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better on serverfault.com?

Comment: Everything I'm reading appears to be fine too, but I'm curious what results you get from sending an email to mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com - as this should check ALL your records, not just the spf.

Comment: I tried to check the records with unlocktheinbox.com and here what is says: bit.ly/wYr39h . It also fails!

Comment: Answered at http://serverfault.com/questions/365819/gmail-rejects-emails-openspf-net-fails-the-tests

Answer (score 0):

I've been having serious problems with gmail rejecting legitimate mail. Somewhere I read a suggestion to delete URLs from your signature file. To my amazement, this worked. (My mail client is Eudora, which some of you may dimly remember.)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail have now a postmaster tool you can check your domain/ip reputation, spam rate and in the "Authentication" area you can check DKIM/SPF/DMARC works correctly.

https://gmail.com/postmaster/

I recommend to use the CNAME record for authentication, if you are using the default TXT record also on SPF query this entry return.